# Can I use a Bash alias in a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys, alias

Is it possible to use an alias within a custom shortcut?

For example, suppose I have the alias

```
alias cal="google-chrome --new-window calendar.google.com"
```

Can I create a custom shortcut that binds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to `cal`?

I have tried but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can. You just need to ask the command for an interactive shell.

Let's say your alias is:

```
alias myalias='some cool command here'
```

Your shortcut command must be:

```
bash -i -c "myalias"
```

[image: screenshot of setting up alias in keyboard settings]

Answer (score 5):

No, the commands run by keyboard bindings are not parsed via a shell. Your best bet is to create a directory `bin` in your homedir (`mkdir -p ~/bin`). Write a script named cal that runs your command, save it in `~/bin` and make it executable.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/bin
$ cat > ~/bin/cal << 'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
exec google-chrome --new-window calendar.google.com
EOF
$ chmod +x ~/bin/cal
```

If you didn't have a `bin` directory in your homedir already, you need to log out and back in again for it to be added to your PATH. Once that is done, binding a keyboard binding to run "cal" should do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

a quick alternative, in case it helps anyone in the future

#### to add a "Save Image As.." keyboard shortcut to Chrome as Shift-Ctrl-S

command: `bash -c "xdotool click 3 && sleep 0.5 && xdotool key v;"`

#### also, if you're organized enough to keep a separate file with your shortcuts & then sourcing it at the end of ~/.bashrc for example, the following works & can comes in handy ;)

command: `bash -c ". /tmp/keyboardShortcutsFcns && tefAliasFcn"`

#### content of the "/tmp/keyboardShortcutsFcns" file from the above example:

`# test fcn to be called ( maybe ? ) from a keyboard shortcut
tefAliasFcn(){ notify-send "tef alias function called succesfully !"; }`

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.