# xdotool press key by keycode (press option key)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, xdotool

so I'm trying to make a keyboard shortcut using xdotool. The only thing that I'm missing and that can't find out how to do is this:

How to press the option key on my keyboard. In more general case, and this would solve my problem as well, **how to press a key using xdotool based on keycode** (if you know about other program which can do this, I don't mind using that instead).

I have a windows keyboard and there is this 'option button' (in between `alt gr` and `right ctrl`), when pressed it opens the right-click menu (right next to where the typing cursor is). I need to **press this button in a script** somehow. I found out (using `showkey -k`) that the keycode of this key is *127*, but I can't make xdotool to press it.

Any ideas on how to do this?

PS: I know that I can simulate a right-click by `xdotool click 3` but that doesn't help because the right click then occurs where the mouse pointer is and I need it to happen where the typing cursor is.

Thank you :)

Comment: Not sure how you tried, but see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/872695/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-executes-an-xdotool-command-to-simulate-a-key-pres/872698#872698 you need a little break to prevent a combined keypres (virtual/real). 0.4 second should do. Please mention if this fixes it. Use the xev command to find out the key. ( `xev` + Return, then press your key).

Comment: Thank you, that's probably what I've been looking for. I forgot that it's called the `media key`, so I've been searching for option key, kecodes, etc... 

I'll test it out.

Comment: Okay, cool it works. However I can't get under 0.5s with the first media key press. But it still helps.

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved thanks to the comment from Jacob Vlijm.

The name of the button can be found this way: run `xev`, then press the button and the name shows up in the brackets. In my case it was this: `keycode 135 (keysym 0xff67, Menu)`, here Menu is the name of the key.

Then I could run `xdotool Menu`. However to make it work with a custom shortcut I had to add `sleep` before it, so I ended up with this code:

```
sleep 0.5 && xdotool key 'Menu'
sleep 0.01 && xdotool key 's'
sleep 0.01 && xdotool key 'e'
```

and it works! :)

BTW: The purpose of this whole thing was to quickly switch between spelling languages in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

When adding a keyboard shortcut on Ubuntu 18.04 it is necessary to explicitly run a subprocess:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 0.4 && xdotool key Menu"
```

Comment: still needed on Ubuntu 22.04, sleep 0.1 is enough but 0.01 is too little