# Where is Control-V defined? How? Can it be changed?

Tags: shortcut-keys

If I look under Settings >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts, I don't see anything related to Control-C, -X or -V.  Where are they defined?  And how?  Suppose I want to change their actions to some other shortcut key, how would I do it?

With help in the comments, I am able to define a hotkey to do the paste action using `xdotool`: `xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+shift+v`.

In addition, I would like to add a script: `xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+shift+v && some_script`.  That fails, but with further help from the comments, I'm finding that `/bin/bash -c "xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+shift+v && some_script"` does work!

Comment: They're implemented internally by the desktop environment and I don't think you can change what they do. Even if you bind a shortcut to Ctrl V, it will still perform pasting action. Although there may be tricks to get around it, though I'm not aware which specifically.

Comment: Thanks @Sergiy.  Is there a way to bind control-v's action to some other key?  What is, in other words, control-v's action?

Comment: Not really. At least not under GNOME, I don't know about others. The best I can do is make a "copy" of paste, so you can have Ctrl V amd some other key.

Comment: You mean I can define, say `control-y` to be `control-v`?  That would be fine for my purposes.  How would I do that?

Comment: I mean Ctrl+V doing pasting and Ctrl+Y doing pasting. Same action, two different keys. There's a command called `xdotool` which allows you to simulate keypresses, among other things. So you bind that command with required options to a shortcut, and when you press Ctrl Y, it'll say to desktop environment "Ctrl V was pressed, do your thing".

Comment: @Sergiy - ok, `xdotool key ctrl-l` works in a terminal window.  `xdotool key ctrl-shift-v` sort of works, but actually pastes twice.  When I try to define either to a hotkey, it fails.  Thoughts?

Comment: Hi Diagon, the issue is that if you asign a keyboard shortcut to another keyboard shortcut, you are virtually pressing both. If you add a small break of 0.5 sec, it should work if you release the shortcut immediately. Not perfect, but it works.

Comment: @Jacob - That is indeed working, as long as I release immediately.  Do you have thoughts on how I might do something like `xdotool sleep 0.5 key ctrl+v; some_script`?  Adding the script fails, though running the script along with that hotkey, works.

Comment: `xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+shft+v` also seems to work, but fails when I add the script.

Comment: `/bin/bash -c "sleep 0.5 && <xdotool command>"` should work from a shortcut.

Comment: I remembered this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/872695/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-executes-an-xdotool-command-to-simulate-a-key-pres/872698

Comment: @Jacob - thank you, yes.  I had read that one.  Note that I am wanting to add a script to eg the paste command.  `xdotool` in a shortcut is now working, but that in combination with a working script, is not working.

Comment: @JacobVlijm - ok, it seems to be working as "/bin/bash -c "<xdotool_command> && some_script".  If you want to write that up as an answer, I'd accept it!  (I put the answer in the question, but you can move it into an answer.)

Comment: I didn't answer here, because the answer is in the linked dupe :)