# wmctrl && xdotool as keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, google-chrome, xdotool, wmctrl

In my workflow I always have tab 1-3 of chrome as specific pages that never change.

I want to make a keyboard shortcut that will navigate to the second tab with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

If I execute the following bash script from a terminal it will proceed to behave as expected but when I tie it to a keybinding from keyboard shortcut settings in the gui it will only achieve focus on Chrome but not proceed to the second command.

`wmctrl -a chrome && xdotool key Ctrl+2`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try inserting a *sleep* between *wmctrl* and *xdotool* like this:

```
wmctrl -a " Google Chrome" && sleep 0.5s && xdotool key Ctrl+2
```

You can play with increasing/decreasing the *sleep* value if needed.

You could also make your command a little more specific by replacing "chrome" with at least " - Google Chrome". That way, the chances of *wmctrl* picking the wrong window to raise to focus will be reduced. In other words, the longer the string, the less chance there is that *wmctrl* may raise and focus a window of some other application that just happens to have "chrome" in the title as seen by `wmctrl -l` or `wmctrl -lx`.

---

A route using only *xdotool* but still requiring *sleep* is this:

```
xdotool search --name " - Google Chrome" windowactivate %1 && sleep 0.5s && xdotool key Ctrl+2
```

Notes:

- Re. the *sleep* value, I would *not* reduce it to the minimum that seems to work but keep it as high as convenient for the times when your system maybe using resources for other purposes.
- if no units are specified for *sleep*, the default is *seconds* but I like to include `s` in any case.
- the basis for requiring *sleep* when using a keyboard shortcut to run scripts/commands involving *xdotool* is explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/872698/248158).

Comment: I needed to ctrl+l ctrl+c inside chrome to get the url. It works. Thank you