# Is there a shortcut for "Open with another application"?

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, nautilus

In Gnome Files (Nautilus?), is there a shortcut to directly open the "Open with another application" window? If no, is there a way to create one?

I'm running files on 3.36.3 on Ubuntu 20.04, in case that matters.

Comment: Right-click on the document icon, and the "Open with another application" is one of the choices.

Comment: @heynnema That's the one I'm aware of, but it has nothing short about it unfortunately.

Comment: After **clicking** on a document icon to select it, CTRL+ALT+O is shorter than a **right-click**?

Comment: I don't need to click on the document to select it, I can navigate to it with the keyboard. (I've modified my keyboard to have a CTRL+ALT key anyway.) And then it's still two clicks, isn't it? One to open the menu and then another one on "Open with another application"? (But yes, as long as I have the hand on the mouse, the two click sequence is likely faster.)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> may be the closest you can get. Unfortunately, shortcut keys cannot be customized or added anymore in Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [vanadium's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1299025/346573), I got the idea to create a shortcut to trigger this shortcut sequence:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 0.1;  xdotool key Menu; sleep 0.1; xdotool key a;"
```

([This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/872698) explains the need for `bash -c`)

Add this to `Settings > Keyboard shortcuts > Custom shortcuts > +`

[image: Screenshot of Settings]

Comment: ...with the only annoyance that your shortcut will be triggered, whether you are in nautilus or not.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Real pros would probably check whether Nautilus is focused first.