# How to enter email adress pressing function key

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm running  Kubuntu 20.10 desktop.

Howto link my email address to <kbd>F1</kbd> key and by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> in any application enter my email address.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have a custom Keyboard Shortcut (settings, keyboard  shortcuts) and use terminal commands...
[How to get a command to output the contents into Terminal, and my system clipboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656124/how-to-get-a-command-to-output-the-contents-into-terminal-and-my-system-clipboa)
using xsel   -

`echo "myemail@dada.com" | xsel -ib && xsel -ob`

```
you  might have trouble customising to F1 and need another key combo
```

make an alias for the above command, then the custom keyboard shortcut to run it as

```
bash -i -c "aliasname"
```

then ctrl-v to paste

Comment: mine is just an alternative to  Rinzwind's link. also a sleep 0.5 in the middle if needed.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/167969/can-i-use-a-bash-alias-in-a-keyboard-shortcut/640691#640691